# How to remove reversed duplicates from my query result?

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

I solve SQL exercises from Lagunita Stanford and I stopped at Question no.3 (SQL Social-Network Query Exercises). I don't know how to remove reversed duplicates from my query result:

```
    Gabriel    9  |  Cassandra  9
    ------------------------------
    Cassandra  9  |  Gabriel    9
    ------------------------------
    Jessica    11 |  Kyle       12
    ------------------------------
    Kyle       12 |  Jessica    11
```

The answer should be:

```
        Cassandra  9  |  Gabriel    9
        ------------------------------
        Jessica    11 |  Kyle       12
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT h1.name,
   h1.grade,
   h2.name,
   h2.grade          
FROM likes AS likes1
INNER JOIN likes AS likes2
   ON likes1.id1 = likes2.id
   AND likes1.id2 = likes2.id1
INNER JOIN highschooler  AS h1 ON likes1.id1 = h1.id
INNER JOIN highschooler  AS h2 ON likes2.id1 = h2.id
```

Tables:
https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html

And I can't use window functions and cte's.

And I'm curious if this possible to remove duplicates in same query.

Comment: Simplify the problem.  Don't join to highschooler table in this query.  Focus on removing duplicates in the `likes` table only, then joining the results to highschooler as a subquery.  Although window functions and CTEs are not allowed, I assume that subqueries are allowed?

Comment: They are. You're right about simplifying but it doesn't change the core of my problem. There are still reversed duplicates that I need to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current resultset as it is formed contains each pair twice and all you need to do to remove one of the 2 rows is to apply a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT h1.name name1,
       h1.grade grade1,
       h2.name name2,
       h2.grade grade2
FROM likes AS likes1
INNER JOIN likes AS likes2 ON likes1.id1 = likes2.id2 AND likes1.id2 = likes2.id1
INNER JOIN highschooler  AS h1 ON likes1.id1 = h1.id
INNER JOIN highschooler  AS h2 ON likes2.id1 = h2.id
WHERE h1.name < h2.name
```

or it could be:

```
WHERE likes1.id1 < likes1.id2
```

if there is a case of 2 highschoolers having the same name.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o5tedvioBVBKNJVittPZCr/1).
Results:

```
| name1     | grade1 | name2   | grade2 |
| --------- | ------ | ------- | ------ |
| Cassandra | 9      | Gabriel | 9      |
| Jessica   | 11     | Kyle    | 12     |
```

Comment: It would be best to eliminate the name comparison altogether, not just because it would eliminate potential problems with duplicate names, but the duplicates occur on the likes table to start with and comparing integer values is much more efficient than comparing strings.

Comment: *comparing integer values is much more efficient than comparing strings* sure it is. I kept the names comparison as first suggestion just because this is what the expected results show that the OP wants. I would prefer the comparison of the ids and as a later thought I would rather set it in the ON clause.

Comment: @beginsql You realize that this ONLY returns duplicate pairs, not just removes them from the query.  If you have any `likes` that are one sided, this query will not return those.  If this is what you want then great, but the title question nor the example data or explanation have any clarification in that regard.

Comment: *You realize that this ONLY returns duplicate pairs* this is what the OP's code does and it is obvious from this condition: `ON likes1.id1 = likes2.id2 AND likes1.id2 = likes2.id1`.

Comment: That's why I changed my answer to reference the OP directly.  I realize that you were just building off the answer, but especially with beginners I often see that the question and sample data don't always sufficiently encompass the actual situation.  They often miss critical details like this.  The fact that he was asking for a solution solved by a simple WHERE condition made me doubt...